# How to create App Engine using API from existing index?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-appsearch, elastic-enterprise-search

There is a way to create engine from exiting index using the Kibana UI. Does any one know how to create engine from existing index using python API or rest API

[image: App Search Creation using Kibana]